# AttributeError: 'PGDialect_psycopg2' object has no attribute 'dbapi_type_map'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, aiopg

After updating all the plugins on the python server, it now raises

```
File "D:\Python362\lib\site-packages\aiopg\utils.py", line 72, in __await__
    resp = yield from self._coro
  File "D:\Python362\lib\site-packages\aiopg\sa\connection.py", line 116, in _execute
    return ResultProxy(self, cursor, self._dialect, result_map)
  File "D:\Python362\lib\site-packages\aiopg\sa\result.py", line 234, in __init__
    self._metadata = ResultMetaData(self, cursor.description)
  File "D:\Python362\lib\site-packages\aiopg\sa\result.py", line 103, in __init__
    typemap = dialect.dbapi_type_map
AttributeError: 'PGDialect_psycopg2' object has no attribute 'dbapi_type_map'
```

[Plugins List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEqvZ.png)

Comment: See https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg/issues/411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was all about sqlalchemy, downgrade to 1.1.15 solved the problem.